# File.length() different than windows, file contents still equal?

Tags: java, file-io, junit, size, java-io

### Read the update at the bottom

I've been scratching my head over this for a few hours and cannot seem to figure this out.

For a unit test, we copy a file to a temporary location and run soms scenario's on it. This file copy does VERY weird things. This only happens with PDF files, images were not affected. I've tried a few different ways of copying/gathering file sizes and all do the same thing.

- The file.length() is not consistent with what windows lists. java thinks the file is larger (roughly 25% more bytes)
- When the file/bytes are read/copied/etc they end up with the number of bytes JAVA reports. (too many)
- Intellij reports both input and output files as identical.  (possible due to intellij using java for its diffs)
- when i open both files notepad++, there are a few differences. All text based information (it is a pdf) is identical. data wrapped in 'stream' tags is different!

the original:

xÚ¥‘=OÃ@†÷ü

the new file:

xÚ¥ï¿½=Oï¿½@ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½

This leads me to suspect an encoding issue or something alike...

But...

- Why does this happen on a byte per byte copy?
- Why does this happen when using a simple file.length()?

Has anyone come across something like this or knows in which direction i should search?

Upon request: This is the code used to copy the files:

`assetFile = TempFileUtil.createTempFile(transformationId + "_" + inputFile.getName());
        FileUtils.copyFile(inputFile, assetFile);`

and the createTempFile method is:

`public static File createTempFile(final String filename) {
        return new File(baseOutputPath, filename);
    }`

## update

I've discoverd that the fault was not with the copying but with the way resources are handled in unit tests. 
The /src/resources/ folder contents are moved/linked/copied to targer/test-classes/ folder so it is accessible in unit tests etc... and that is where is goes wrong...
I'm still trying to find out why this is failing.

Comment: You're not maybe checking the KB / MB and incorrectly assuming this is 1000 / 1000^2 bytes, are you? (it's 1024 / 1024^2 bytes)

Comment: I'm comparing with the exact number of bytes listed by windows in the properties window.

Comment: My guess is that you are not doing a byte-by-byte copy.  Show us the copy code.

Comment: I've used [apache commons FileUtils.copyFile()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18955721/file-length-different-than-windows-file-contents-still-equal#comment27995028_18955996)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is based on assumptions that turned out to be false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the maven resources plugin was badly configured.
By default only a few basic image types are configured as "do not filter these" when filtering is set to true. adding PDF to this list solved the problem.

`<plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <nonFilteredFileExtensions>
                        <nonFilteredFileExtension>pdf</nonFilteredFileExtension>
                        <nonFilteredFileExtension>jpg</nonFilteredFileExtension>
                        <nonFilteredFileExtension>jpeg</nonFilteredFileExtension>
                        <nonFilteredFileExtension>gif</nonFilteredFileExtension>
                        <nonFilteredFileExtension>png</nonFilteredFileExtension>
                        <nonFilteredFileExtension>tif</nonFilteredFileExtension>
                        <nonFilteredFileExtension>tiff</nonFilteredFileExtension>
                        <nonFilteredFileExtension>bmp</nonFilteredFileExtension>
                    </nonFilteredFileExtensions>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>`

Answer (score 1):

You're almost certainly not copying it correctly: for example, you're using Readers and Writers where you should be using input and output streams.

Comment: +1 - He certainly should not be doing that for PDF files, which are more definitely NOT text.

Comment: i've been using 
org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.copyFile()
and as second test used BufferedInputStreams